# Java code for read .CSV file and FTP server but data writing in single line

Tags: java, ftp

I have case Java code for read `.CSV` file which contains multiple lines data with headers and write into `FTP` server but data writing in single line.

Can any one guide how to get proper output same like input file.

**Code:**

```
finally{
    try {

        // Cookcounty FTP start
        if (EnrollmentEDI.Status != "FAILURE") {

            if (CountyPlanNumbersList.contains(samp.PlanNumber())) {
                CommonMessages.logGenericTrace("CountyFTp start");
                com.vitria.connectors.ftp.DynamicFTPTargetInfo CountyFTP = com.vitria.connectors.ftp.FTPConnectorUserLib.createDynamicFTPTargetInfo();
                CountyFTP.setHostname(props.getProperty("County_HostName"));
                CountyFTP.setUsername(props.getProperty("County_UserName"));
                CountyFTP.setPassword(props.getProperty("County_Password"));
                CountyFTP.setDirectory(props.getProperty("County_RemoteDirectory"));
                FileInputStream fins = null;
                BufferedInputStream bins = null;
                DataInputStream dins = null;

                String line1 = "";
                File CookCoutyOut1 = new File(utility.CountyOutputFolderPath + "/" + ccformattedDate + ".csv");

                CommonMessages.logGenericTrace("CountyFileName=" + CookCoutyOut1);
                fins = new FileInputStream(CookCoutyOut1);
                bins = new BufferedInputStream(fins);
                dins = new DataInputStream(bins);
                while (dins.available() != 0) {
                    line1 = line1 + dins.readLine();
                    ;
                }
                if (!(line1.trim().equals(""))) {
                    CookCountyOriginal = line1;
                }
                dins.close();
                bins.close();
                fins.close();
                //  CommonMessages.logGenericTrace("CookCountyOriginal =" + CookCountyOriginal);
                String cookyFileName = ccformattedDate + ".csv";
                CommonMessages.logGenericTrace("cookyFileName =" + cookyFileName);
                EventDef newEventFile2 = (EventDef) (vtFileConnectorEvents.dataFileEventInterfaceHelper.getMetaObject().findDef("dataFileEvent"));
                Object[] outParamsFile2 = {CookCountyOriginal.getBytes(), cookyFileName};
                EventBody out3 = null;
                out3 = JctLib.createEventBody(newEventFile2, outParamsFile2);
                getOutPort8(CountyFTP).push(out3);
            }
            CommonMessages.logGenericTrace("CountyFTp END");
        }

    } catch (Exception c) {
        CommonMessages.logGenericTrace(" *** INFORCE ENROLLMENT PROCESS : ERR IN County :-" + c.toString());
        FTPtrack = "" + c.toString();
        FTPtrack = "FTP TRANSFER TO MAINFRAME :" + FTPtrack.replaceAll(":", ",") + " - FAILED";
        EnrollmentEDI.Track = EnrollmentEDI.Track + " FTPEXCEPTION : " + FTPtrack + "\n";
        //CommonMessages.logGenericTrace("Exception in ACK FTPtrack======="+FTPtrack);
        EnrollmentEDI.Status = "FAILURE";
        EnrollmentEDI.Intouchtrack = EnrollmentEDI.Intouchtrack + "\n" + "FTPEXCEPTION :" + c.toString() + "\n-RESOLUTION:" + props.getProperty("5");
        com.glic.excp.handlers.GLICPCExcpHandler glicpc = new com.glic.excp.handlers.GLICPCExcpHandler();
        glicpc.handleComponentException(c, ctx);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine--) method only reads up to the newline. The string returned does not include the newline character. See the contract of [`DataInput#readLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readLine--).

To add the newline back on, you could replace this loop:

```
while (dins.available() != 0) {
    line1 = line1 + dins.readLine();;
}
```

with one that adds either `"\n"` or `"\r\n"` or `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to the end of each line read, depending on what kind of line endings the mainframe expects.

But there are a few other problems with this code. You should be checking for a `null` result from `readLine()` to detect end-of-file, not looking at `dins.available()`. And you should be using `BufferedReader`, not `DataInputStream` as the documentation suggests. [`DataInputStream#readLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine--) has been **deprecated** since JDK 1.1.

The loop would look like this if you continue using `available()` and `DataInputStream`:

```
String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
while (dins.available() != 0) {
    line1 = line1 + dins.readLine() + lineSeparator;
}
```

Or like this in a more up-to-date style of Java, using BufferedReader, a try-with-resources statement, and just using `"\n"` for a newline instead of line.separator:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(CookCoutyOut1)))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        line1 += line + "\n";
    }
}
```

You should find out what kind of line endings the machine you're uploading this to expects. Using `System.getProperty("line.separator")` is going to give you the default line separator *for the machine you're running on*, but that's not necessarily the same as what the machine you're sending it to wants. In the last example I just wrote an explicit `"\n"`. You could replace that with `"\r\n"` if the mainframe wants carriage return/linefeed (CRLF).

Comment: Hi thanks for quick reply we can see here we are not reading line by line we are reading entire file and assigning to File CookCoutyOut1
 String line1 = "";
 File CookCoutyOut1 = new File(utility.CountyOutputFolderPath + "/" + ccformattedDate + ".csv");

Comment: can you please confirm is it works ..?

                           while (dins.available() != 0) {
                                  line1 = line1 + dins.readLine();;
                                  System.getProperty("line.separator");
                           }
                           if (!(line1.trim().equals(""))) { 
                               CookCountyOriginal = line1;
                           }

Comment: You need to add the line separator to each line. I'll update my answer to show an example.